# Processing a large XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, data-science, generator

I have a file of almost 2 GB. The task is to translate the xml file into a database. To process it, I use a custom generator function. While the file is being processed by the accumulation effect, my RAM is loaded and the process ends without completing it (killed). Please tell me what is wrong in my code. As far as I know, the generator function method is used for very large files and should not fill the RAM completely.

```
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import chain
import os, glob


def generator_get_element(xmlfile):
    #generator to get elements in a xml file
    doc = etree.iterparse(xmlfile, events=('start', 'end'))
    _, root = next(doc)
    start_tag = None
    for event, element in doc:
        if event == 'start' and start_tag is None:
            start_tag = element.tag
        if event == 'end' and element.tag == start_tag:
            yield element
            start_tag = None
            root.clear()


def get_info_from_element():
    # parse all information from the received element of the xml file
    # download_file()
    intermediate_list = list()
    os.chdir("./xml_files")
    for file in glob.glob("*.xml"):
        my_fun = generator_get_element(file)
        for i in my_fun:
            try:
                parts = ([i.text] +
                list(chain(*([etree.tostring(c)] for c in i.getchildren()))) +
                [i.tail])

                filter_parts = filter(None, parts)
                for i in filter_parts:
                    bf = BeautifulSoup(i, 'lxml')
                    intermediate_list.append(bf.text)
                intermediate_list = [line.replace('\n', ' ') for line in intermediate_list]
                trade_name = ' '.join(list(set(intermediate_list[4].split(' '))))
                insert_program(
                    db_con,
                    id=re.sub(">", "", intermediate_list[1].strip()),
                    type=re.sub(">", "", intermediate_list[2].strip()),
                    tradeName=trade_name.strip(),
                    ico=re.sub("[^0-9]", "", intermediate_list[5].strip()),
                    fullAddress=re.sub(">", "", intermediate_list[6].strip())
                                )
                intermediate_list.clear()
            except:
                intermediate_list.clear()
                pass
```

Comment: @slothrop Can you tell me what is the best way to process these files? To take in blocks and minimize the load on RAM. Thank you

Comment: Have a look at the linked question - the people answering there seem to have a deeper understanding than I do :)

Comment: @slothrop It seems to be what I need. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Have you considered using the `huge_tree=True` argument for the [XMLParser](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html)?

Comment: @Jens Haven't tried it, but it's an option. Now I will test
Tried many options, but many load the system. Locally enough memory, not on the server